# Mapping transformation from one coordinate space to another

Tags: math, opengl, matrix, 3d, transformation

I have two 4x4 transformation matrices that define two coordinate spaces. I am trying to express a translate transformation in one coordinate space in terms of the other. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let A be the matrix from space *a* to global space *G*.

Let B be the matrix from space *b* to global space *G*.

Then to get from *a* to *b* we first transform with A to get into *G* and then with B^-1 (the inverse of B) to get from *G* to *b*. Hence

```
v_b = B^-1 · A ·v_a
```